# Get active filters in Category/View Block in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation, filter

I want to return all active filters in a custom View Block in module catalog. While the categories are returned in the layered navigation view, this always returns an empty result:

```
class CategoryView extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        // Doesn't work, filters are always empty
        $state = $this->_catalogLayer->getState();
        print_r($state->getFilters());

        return $this;
    }

}
```

Do I have to call some function first to trigger loading the filters?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as well. I guess that the _prepareLayout function is run, before any filters are applied and that these filters are applied later in the lifecycle. No clue yet on how to solve this.